# C++ Member to member function pointers OR event driven programming

Tags: c++, event-handling, wxwidgets

I come from the C# world so events and event handlers are everyday stuff.
Recently i have been studying about wxWidgets
I've been googling about this for a week now and i have found that most C++ programmers hardly understand the term "event" or "callback", perhaps it's ambiguous in the world of C++.

Here's a simple example of the event model.

```
class A{
public:
    A(){
       child.MySuperClickEvent = this.HandleSuperClick;
    }
private:
    B child;

    void HandleSuperClick(B child){
        // do stuff
    }
 }


class B{
public:
    /*TBA*/ MySuperClickEvent;
private:
    void ClickPrivate(){
        MySuperClickEvent(this);
    }
}
```

class B has it's own designated purpose and when finished it triggers an event.
The idea is that class B shouldn't have any knowledge of it's domain, making it more reusable.

I have read about std::function<> and function pointers. which all seems to take examples in handling static functions but as soon as were talking "Member to Member" things starts to get greasy.

So summarize, the question is simple. How do i make a member function pointer that can be assigned to a member externally?

Comment: Updated the question. Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

There are a great many ways to implement such things, varying in terms of memory overheads, how many callbacks are supported, thread safety, use of e.g. `weak_ptr`s to see if the objects involved still exist etc..

Just as a taste to get you started - here's a simple single-threaded "observer" implementation doing basically what you ask for in the question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct Observer
{
    virtual ~Observer() { }
    virtual void on_event_x() { }
};

class Observable
{
  public:
    void add_observer(Observer& o)
    {
        observers_.push_back(&o);
    }

    void do_some_stuff()
    {
        std::cout << "before 1st event\n";
        fire_event_x();
        std::cout << "between 1st & 2nd events\n";
        fire_event_x();
        std::cout << "after 2nd event\n";
    }

  private:
    std::list<Observer*> observers_;

    void fire_event_x()
    {
        for (auto& observer : observers_)
            observer->on_event_x();
    }
};

struct My_Observer : Observer
{
    My_Observer(int id) : id_(id) { }

    void on_event_x() override
    {
        std::cout << "My_Observer::on_event_x() id " << id_ << '\n';
    }

    int id_;
};

int main()
{
    My_Observer my_observer_1 { 1 };
    My_Observer my_observer_2 { 2 };
    Observable x;
    x.add_observer(my_observer_1);
    x.add_observer(my_observer_2);
    x.do_some_stuff();
}
```

Runtime output:

```
before 1st event
My_Observer::on_event_x() id 1
My_Observer::on_event_x() id 2
between 1st & 2nd events
My_Observer::on_event_x() id 1
My_Observer::on_event_x() id 2
after 2nd event
```

If that doesn't suit you functionally, please say exactly why.

Comment: Thanks for you time. The term "Observer" is pretty foreign to me. However reading the code: it does seem like a sort of event implementation. But as far as i can see you're not attaching any callbacks/functions to this "observer" but rather you inherit and override the "on_event_x" function. I will tinker a little with this solution

Comment: @CyberFox: You're welcome.  [Observer](qt_config) is one of the classic design patterns and worth learning - if you have time and interest, the "Gang of Four" book [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) will give you a good, gentle introduction to that and other very common patterns.  As you say, the implementation I chose to illustrate uses virtual dispatch (C++'s mechanism for runtime polymorphism) rather than explicit function pointers or `std::function<>` instances, but all of those are options - the latter the most flexible, but `remove_observer()` gets trickier.

Comment: i tried your solution-ish for about a week now. I mixed in Templates to make a generic solution. But it seems when templates and inheritance is combined as a certain level, C++ stops doing type-inference or something. Like the iterator can't find the loop variable. I'm not sure if this is a glitch in the C++ compiler or me being incompetent. (prolly the latter)

Comment: @CyberFox: I can't guess without seeing any code... if you can boil your issues down to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), feel free to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

As this question is tagged `wxWidgets`, let me answer the more narrow variant of it, i.e. how to use member function as event handler in wxWidgets:

This is done with the help of [Bind()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_evt_handler.html#a0f30c8fa5583b4a5f661897d63de3b62) method which can be used with a member function directly (you pass the pointer to the function itself and the object to call it on) or any arbitrary functor, i.e. anything that can be called using the standard function call syntax, such as an `std::function<>` object which, in turn, can be used to store any callable object.

Comment: the documentation hardly provides enough information and the event sample they link is a ~600 lines file on GitHub. Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: You should really be capable of grepping even a 6000 line sample for the function you're interested in, but let me [do this](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.0/samples/event/event.cpp#L514) for you.

Comment: I might be able to navigate ~6000 lines of C# code. So yes i really should get on that horse. I did find line 514 with ctrl+f on "Bind" too. But i'm still a little lost. wxEVT_BUTTON global constant. And It's simply just a number. The documentation says EventType but what does that really imply? If i define a different constant will it attach to a different event. or doesn't it matter what i put there?

Comment: `wxEVT_BUTTON` is the event type constant corresponding to button click events. It is, of course, documented in this class [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_button.html).